# Convert from localField to let - $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to adapt my code so I could after use the pipeline to $project only the fields I need.

This first code is achieving the result expected;

```
  Order.aggregate([
      { $unwind: "$candidate" },
      { $match: { "candidate.groupId": "A" } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "candidate.autonomousId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "candidateData",
        },
      },          
    ]).toArray();
```

The second one doesn't return the same output. It returns an empty candidateData.

```
Order.aggregate([
          { $unwind: "$candidate" },
          { $match: { "candidate.groupId": "A" } },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "users",
              let: { id: "$candidate.autonomousId" },
              pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$id"] } } }],
              as: "candidateData",
            },
          },
        ]).toArray();
```

What am I doing wrong when I try to write in the second way? I couldn't find my syntax mistake.

Comment: [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is a JavaScript keyword.

Comment: Then how would I use `let` on the Node Driver? I'm trying to escape that and it's not working.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using ?

Comment: I don't know mongodb. However I found some documentation page about `$let`. Isn't that the one you need?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar 3.6.3

Comment: No, it's not @tevemadar.

Comment: @igortp Try wrapping let in quotes and check.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I've tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @igortp Can you share a [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/) URL with some test data and your query?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan https://mongoplayground.net/p/xb6XzMQjLU1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `candidate.autonomousId` is an array (contrary to its name) and you are using the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operator to compare `$$id` (array) with `_id` (`ObjectId`), the pipeline returns no `User` documents in `candidateData`. You should use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator instead.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$candidate"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "candidate.groupId": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        id: "$candidate.autonomousId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "candidateData",  
    },
  },
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ePfXjKoJxf)

---

I would recommend renaming the let variable `ids` for clarity.